# Dynamically added RequiredFieldValidator is not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have linkbutton on its click event which adds one Textbox and RequiredValidator Dynamically.

```
protected void lnkAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
TextBox txt = new TextBox();
RequiredFieldValidator ReqAuthor = new RequiredFieldValidator();

txt.ID = "txtAuthorName";
txt.CssClass = "form_3";

ReqAuthor.ID = "ReqAuthor"
ReqAuthor.SetFocusOnError = true;
ReqAuthor.EnableClientScript = true;
ReqAuthor.Enabled = true;
ReqAuthor.ControlToValidate = txt.ID;
ReqAuthor.Display = ValidatorDisplay.Dynamic;
ReqAuthor.ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Author Name.";
ReqAuthor.Font.Size = 12;

pnlAuthorTextBox.Controls.Add(txt);

pnlAuthorTextBox.Controls.Add(ReqAuthor);
}
```

In this code No Error i get at runtime. Code runs Smoothly.

Textbox also get created. But RequiredFieldValidator does not seems as working.

Thanks in advance.

Please help

Comment: yes this is dynamic textbox with dynamic validator.

Comment: as i don't find anything wrong with your code except the semi colon that's missing. But if you are saying that you are not getting any error, i would neglect that as a Typo error. Other than that your code runs very well. What browser you are using?

Comment: It is not working in any browser Firefox, Chrome both tried

Comment: can you share your button html?

Comment: <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkAdd" runat="server" CausesValidation="false" OnClick="lnkAdd_Click">+ Add Author</asp:LinkButton> <asp:Panel ID="pnlAuthorTextBox" runat="server" Width="400">
            
            
        </asp:Panel>

Comment: Final Button is <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" />

Comment: on which button you want to validate the textbox? Linkbutton or simple Button. If its Link button check my answer.

Comment: i check on Simple Button

Answer (score 0):

This is where you have the problem : `CausesValidation="true"`

```
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" CausesValidation="true" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" Text="Submit" />
```

and your validator will start working and let me know if that solved your issue

Comment: this is not my submit button in this button click the dynamic text box is created